# How to set multiple fonts in TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I already use my custom font in TCPDF. Now I tried to add the bold font type (also by adding the 'style' parameter), but without success:

```
$objPdf->SetFont('opensanscondensedlight', '', 12);
$objPdf->SetFont('opensanscondensedbold', 'B', 12);
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: What does “without success” mean?

Comment: That only the last line works. In this case everything is shown with the bold font, ignoring all css declarations like font-family and font-weight.

Comment: Could you update your post with a broader code example? It seems that you're mixing direct rendering (`TCPDF::Cell` et al.) with HTML rendering (`TCPDF::writeHTMLCell`).

Comment: No, I loaded HTML. But I switched to mPDF, wich works better with multiple fonts...